# Omnipay 2Checkout Library Out Of Date?

Tags: omnipay, 2checkout

The required parameters for 2Checkout as stated [in the docs](https://www.2checkout.com/documentation/checkout/parameters/) are `li_#_type`, `li_#_name` etc. but the 2Checkout [Omnipay library](https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-2checkout) doesn't seem to have this functionality.

Is this library just out of date now?

Answer (score 2):

The 2checkout library was written based off of these docs: http://www.2checkout.com/documentation/Advanced_User_Guide.pdf

Which no longer exist, apparently. So yes, the library has become out of date and will need to be rewritten based on the new documentation and required parameters. From what I can tell 2checkout isn't versioning their API, so I'm not able to indicate which version this library addresses.